# Swift. Calendar. veryShortWeekdaySymbols start with Monday

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I would like to display very Short Weekday symbols starting from Monday.

When I do this in playground:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
print(calendar.veryShortWeekdaySymbols)
```

Result is: `["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]`

I tried also to change firstWeekday:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.firstWeekday = 2
print(calendar.veryShortWeekdaySymbols)
```

But the result is the same

Comment: I think it is designed to give you the DoW always starting with Sunday, so that you can easily index it. It's not that hard to rotate the array once, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
let firstWeekday = 2 // -> Monday

var symbols = calendar.veryShortWeekdaySymbols
symbols = Array(symbols[firstWeekday-1..<symbols.count]) + symbols[0..<firstWeekday-1]
```

Result -> ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

Comment: Instead of hardcoded `firstWeekday` you can use `calendar.firstWeekday`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the first element and append it:

```
var weekdaySymbols = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).veryShortWeekdaySymbols
weekdaySymbols.append(weekdaySymbols.remove(at: weekdaySymbols.startIndex))
weekdaySymbols  // ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"]
```